# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40 cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have strange error with Spring configuration and javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory. It throws me java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40 cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory

My configuration is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

   <context:annotation-config />
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.dhl.cas" />
   <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="umDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.um.driver:oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.um.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.um.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.um.password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="${db.connection.initialSize:10}" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="-1" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="${db.connection.maxActive:100}" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="-1" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="${db.validation.query:select 1 from dual}" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="validationQueryTimeout" value="5" />
        <property name="connectionProperties" value="oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout=${db.read.timeout:60000};oracle.net.READ_TIMEOUT=${db.net.timeout:60000}" />
        
    </bean>

    <bean id="umJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="umDataSource">

        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="umNamedJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="umJdbcTemplate" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
    
    
   <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="umDataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
      <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
        <property name="showSql" value="false" />
      </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>
 
  <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />
 
    

    <bean name="internalLdapBean" class="com.dhl.resp.authentication.LDAP">
        <property name="ldapUrl" value="${ldap.url}" />
        <property name="ldapPrincipalSuffix" value="${ldap.principalsuffix}" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="externalLdapBean" class="com.dhl.resp.authentication.LDAPAD">
        <property name="ldapUrl" value="${ldap_uag.url}" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean name="umDao" class="com.dhl.resp.authentication.dao.UmDaoImpl">
        <property name="umNamedJdbcTemplate" ref="umNamedJdbcTemplate" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean name="umAuthenticationHandler" class="com.dhl.resp.authentication.UmAuthenticationHandlerImpl" >
        <property name="umDao" ref="umDao" />
        <property name="internalLdap" ref="internalLdapBean" />
        <property name="externalLdap" ref="externalLdapBean" />
        <property name="skipLockedUsers" value="${skip.locked.users.during.login:true}" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="SDCFilter"
    class="com.dhl.cas.support.SDCFilter"/>
</beans>
```

Error which it throws is :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [/appl/dev_cas/webapps/cas/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/applicationContext-beans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40 cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized_aroundBody0(SafeContextLoaderListener.java:75)
        at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized_aroundBody1$advice(SafeContextLoaderListener.java:57)
        at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SafeContextLoaderListener.java:1)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4678)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5139)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1848)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40 cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.createEntityManagerFactoryProxy(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:464)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
        ... 56 more
```

Can someone plese give me a tip how to solve this issue? Thanks

My mvn dependency:tree

```
   com.dhl.cas:cas:war:3.0.10.0
[INFO] +- com.dhl.resp:authentication-core:jar:1.0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:jar:1.3.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.microsoft.azure:adal4j:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:jar:4.5:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- com.nimbusds:lang-tag:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.1.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.1.4.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.jasig.cas:cas-server-webapp:war:3.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.inspektr:inspektr-audit:jar:1.0.7.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.inspektr:inspektr-common:jar:1.0.7.GA:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.inspektr:inspektr-support-spring:jar:1.0.7.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.inspektr:inspektr-error:jar:1.0.7.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-cas:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jasig.cas.client:cas-client-core:jar:3.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:runtime
[INFO] |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:runtime
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.1.0:runtime
[INFO] +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.2.9:test
[INFO] +- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jasig.cas:cas-server-core:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jasig.service:person-directory-impl:jar:1.5.0-RC6:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.12:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jasig.service:person-directory-api:jar:1.5.0-RC6:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml:xmldsig:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.perf4j:perf4j:jar:log4jonly:0.9.14:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.webflow:spring-webflow:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.webflow:spring-binding:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.webflow:spring-js:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework.webflow:spring-js-resources:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-jexl:commons-jexl:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.6.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.18:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.18:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:jar:1.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.narupley:not-going-to-be-commons-ssl:jar:0.3.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-ext-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity-engine-core:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.64:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.64:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.opensaml:openws:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:2.2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.io7m.xom:xom:jar:1.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache-extras.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:r07:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.8:runtime
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.8:runtime
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.5.8:runtime
[INFO] \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
```

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with you dependencies? What do you have on the classpath related to JPA (Spring, Hibernate...)

Comment: I add mvn dependency:tree

Answer (score 0):

Spring 5.3 is not compatible with jpa 2.1. See this [compatibility matrix](https://github.com/ghusta/matrice-versions-spring-hibernate) (sorry, it's in French).

A solution is to upgrade to hibernate 5.3.